# PHPMailer - No email will be sent

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

So I'm trying to just send some basic email from my site to return forgot passwords. I'm not sure why its not working. I've looked around and tried to jus copy and have also tried modifying others' examples.

```
<?php
$to = 'temp@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'PHPMAILER';
$message = 'TEST MESSAGE';

require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP();                        // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                 // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';              // Enable encryption (tls), 'ssl'          also accepted
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';          // Specify main and backup SMTP     servers
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->isHTML(true);                    // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Username = 'temp@gmail.com';     // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';            // SMTP password


$mail->SetFrom = 'webmaster@website.net';
$mail->FromName = 'webmaster';

$mail->WordWrap = 100;                                // Set word wrap to 50     characters
//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');       // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');  // Optional name

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $message;

$mail->addAddress($to,);     // Add a recipient

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.<br>';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>
```

I've tested both port 465 and 587. I'm using Hostgator and I think they are restricting port 587 from use so I've been trying to use port 465. I tested the connection with telnet and it worked fine. When I try to go to the page that is in my test.php it returns a white screen until it times out and I receive error 504. I don't know where it goes wrong but hopefully somebody can help. Thank you.

Comment: why are you not using hostgators mail server (your paying for it)

Comment: I wanted it to be automatic but from what I saw the mail server wouldn't do it. Either that or maybe I'm looking at the wrong thing.

Comment: Hey thanks for the heads up on hostgator mail server Dagon. I tried looking into it again and got it too work. I changed the Host to `$mail->Host  mail.domainname` and the username and password into my cpanel email address. Thanks again.

Comment: don't know what people don't use there own hosts mail server as the first option - but then people are weird

Comment: Error 504 is a gateway timeout - there will probably be something in your server logs about it, but you should check through [the troubleshooting guide too](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).